# A topological space with a transitive action.

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

Let $X$ be a topological space on which a topological group $G$ acts transitively.
Given $x\in X$ let 
$$stab(x)=\{g\in G\;|\; gx=x\}.$$

I want to show that $X$ is homeomorphic to $G/stab(x)$ for any given $x\in X$.
I Know that when $G$ acts transitively then there exists only one orbit so that the quotient 
$X/G$ has only one element $[x]$ which is the class of any element $x\in X$ but i can't find a one to one correspondance between $X$ and $G/stab(x)$. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Homeomorphism is false in general, but you get a continuous bijection. Hint: Consider group G equipped with the discrete topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in X$. Define a map $f:G\to X$ by $f(g)=g\cdot x$ for $g\in G$. Note that if $g_1,g_2\in G$ are in the same left coset of $stab(x)$, then $$g_1^{-1}g_2(x)=x,$$and so $$g_2(x)=g_1(x),$$in other words,$$f(g_1)=f(g_2).$$Hence, $f$ induces a well defined map $\tilde{f}:G/stab(x)\to X$. The verification that $\tilde{f}$ is a continuous bijection is standard. However, as studiosus kindly suggests, it is not necessarily an open map. For example, one can take $X$ to have the trivial topology $\tau=\{\phi,X\}$. In order to obtain a homeomorphism, further assumptions are needed.

Comment: Just try to prove continuity of the inverse of $\tilde f$ and see how far you will get.

Comment: @studiosus Thanks for your remark. I changed my answer.

Comment: One way to get homeomorphism is to assume that the group action is _proper_: The map $G\times X\to X$ (defining the action) is a proper map.

Comment: @studiosus I would guess $X$ needs to be Hausdorff, in order for a proper map to yield a homemorphism. What do you think?

Comment: No, this is not enough, you can take, say, $X={\mathbb R}$ with the standard topology and the group $G$ of real numbers, equipped with the discrete topology. I think, if you assume that $X$ is Hausdorff  and the group action is _proper_ then you do get a homeomorphism.

Comment: @studiosus Or, you can assume $X$ Hausdorff and $G$ compact.

Comment: Yes, compact would definitely work, but compact G is much weaker than a proper action. An action $G\times X\to X$ is proper if preimages of compacts are compact under this map.